# Embedding TensorFlow Python program in C++

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, tensorflow

I'm stressing out and really need help at this point. I have a Python3.6 program that imports csv, tensorflow, numpy, and "from tensorflow import keras". This program (which I can't post) uses Estimators and its  eval and predict methods, which  makes use of multiple threads.

I'm trying to embed Python into a C++ program that would then call the mentioned script multiple times at different points in the single threaded code. I got the Python program to run, but the problem comes when calling `Py_Finalize();`, which is causing this error:

> Exception ignored in: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1289, in _shutdown
>       assert tlock.locked()
>
> SystemError: (built-in method locked of _thread.lock object at 0x7fa340764f08) returned a result with an error set

Stepping through the code, I noticed when `PyRun_File()` returned, my single threaded C++ program added ~10 threads related to TensorFlow. Here's all the embeded python logic in my C++ code with commented out code of things I've tried/messed around with.

```
void run_python_script(string mode, string model, std::vector<int>* y_test = nullptr) {
const char* SCRIPT_PATH = "../PATH";

/* Setup embedded Python*/
Py_SetProgramName(Py_DecodeLocale(SCRIPT_PATH, NULL));

Py_Initialize();
PyEval_InitThreads();
//  Py_DECREF(PyImport_ImportModule("tensorflow"));
//  PyThreadState* threadState = PyEval_SaveThread();
//  PyGILState_STATE gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();
//  PyObject* pGlobals = PyDict_New();
//  PyDict_SetItemString(pGlobals, "__builtins__", PyEval_GetBuiltins());

PyObject* m_pMainModule = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
PyObject* pGlobals = PyModule_GetDict(m_pMainModule);

const wchar_t *script_args[] = { L"REMOVED FROM SNIPPET", NULL };
const wchar_t **_argv = script_args;
int _argc = sizeof(script_args) / sizeof(script_args[0]) - 1;
PySys_SetArgv(_argc, const_cast<wchar_t **>(_argv));

FILE *file = _Py_fopen(SCRIPT_PATH, "r+");
if (file != NULL) {
    cout << "Running script..." << endl;
    PyRun_File(file, SCRIPT_PATH, Py_file_input, pGlobals, pGlobals);
    assert(!PyErr_Occurred());
} else
    cerr << "Couldn't find a python script to run";
fclose(file);
//  PyGILState_Release(gstate);
//  PyEval_RestoreThread(threadState);
Py_Finalize();      //@TODO WHY DOES PROGRAM CRASH HERE ON SCRIPT COMPLETION
/* End embedded Python*/
cout << "Script and file closed." << endl;
```

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Unless you specify the resources Tensorflow will use multi-threading when available.  Also, why are you periodically training?  Might be best to export the model and use infrencers in the C++ app.

Comment: @jman, Sorry, no not periodically training, just predicting and evaluating. And I know TF will use multi-threading, that's not really the problem..